# Lists in field calculator in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

Would anyone please indicate to me why this is not working. I am trying to convert all instances of '02ND' to '2ND' for example where some of the input fields (f1) are already converted and some are not.

In codeblock:

```
 def calc(f1):
 list=['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']

    for i in list:

        if i in f1:
            f1 = f1.replace('0','')
            return f1.replace('0','')
        else:

            return f1
```

I simply call the function calc to populate a new field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just check if your field value is in the remove list:

```
def remove_zero(field):

    remove_list = ['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']

    if field in remove_list:
        field = field.replace('0','')
        return field
    else:
        return field
```

Then you'll want to do:

```
remove_zero(!FIELDNAME!)
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit explanation why the OP's function is not working:

f1 = a string

list= a list

When you are iterating over the list, for each member of list you will get either **positive** or **negative** response. So your list has nine members; you will get nine responses(+ and -). Then what the **calc** function will return, whole nine responses or one? Of-course python function will return only one in this case. Since **only one** return is allowed so **calc** function is returning the response for the last member i.e.**'09TH'** and you will get all instances of '09TH' with no leading "0" but **nothing** about all the other instances e.g.'01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH'.

Solution:

**No need to iterate over the list, just check if f1 is in the list.**

```
def calc(f1):
       list = ['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']  
       if f1 in list:
                  f1 = f1.replace('0','')
                  return f1
       else:
                  return f1
```

N.B. Avoid variable declaration with reserved words. You defined a **list variable** named **list**, list is reserved word of python.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the same thing could be accomplished with `!FieldName!.lstrip("0")`.

Comment: +1 Agree, this is the easiest solution with no codeblock necessary.

Comment: Yes if all the field entry needs to be changed then this the best facile way to go.